# Ckeditor Slideshow icon not displayed

Tags: drupal-7, ckeditor, slideshow, ckfinder

I work with drupal 4.4.7 and ckeditor, I want to use  slideshow, plugin of ckeditor.I have installed ckeditor and ckfinder correctly, also i have installed slideshow and turn on this plugin on configuration page, but there is no icon in CKeditor settings "SHOWEDITOR APPEARANCE" tab.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution!

In "sites\all\modules\ckeditor\plugins\slideshow\plugin.js" I added the path to the icon image (line 91):

```js
// Create a toolbar button that executes the above command.
editor.ui.addButton('Slideshow', {
  // The text part of the button (if available) and tooptip.
  label: lang.insertSlideShow,
  command: 'slideshow',
  // The button placement in the toolbar (toolbar group name).
  toolbar: 'insert',
  icon: this.path + 'icons/slideshow.png'
});
```

The button now appears in the configuration CKEditor :)